# Why can't I load an image which is located in the assets catalog?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsimage, nsbundle, asset-catalog

I am trying to build a simple screensaver. The first thing I do is to load the image from the asset catalog with the method `[NSImage imagedNamed:]` which returns a nil value, that would mean that it can't find the image. When I try to load the image directly from the bundle with the method

`[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForImageResource:]`

I also get a nil value. I don't understand why this happens. The image is located in the asset catalog and in the project settings I have set it as a bundle resource.

Comment: `[NSImage imageNamed:]` is for accessing images within your app bundle, not asset catalog.  Why can't you put the image in your app bundle?

Comment: I have optimised versions of my image for retina and non retina macs, so I thought the best way would be the assets catalog. Of course I could put the images directly in the app bundle but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I continued searching on the internet I found out that the screensaver is executed as some kind of plugin and by loading the main bundle I loaded the System Preference bundle which means that I am not able to get my resource by loading the main bundle, instead I have to load the bundle with bundleIdentifier or with the path where the bundle is saved.
So my code looks like this now:

```
NSBundle*bundle=[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.myname.APOD"];
NSImage*image=[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[bundle pathForResource:@"appimage" ofType:@"png"]];
```

Answer (score 5):

You **can** access images in asset catalogs by name, however not using the `imageNamed:` method of `NSImage` -

Instead you can query a bundle for image resources of specific name, e.g. to find an image in the bundle of the class requesting the image you would:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
NSImage *myImage = [bundle imageForResource:@"MyImageName"];
```

where *MyImageName* refers to the name you assigned the image in your asset catalog.